# How dart can get a ten digit timestamp?

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried `print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);` but it return a 13 digit number `1548070662432` , How can I get one like `1547897440`?

Comment: so you dont want milliseconds but you want seconds instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an option:

```
(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).toInt();
```

This will give you the unix timestamp in secods.

Comment: Or more succinctly as `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000`

Comment: Perfect answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt method **DateTime.utc** as below:

```
  static void getCurrentDateUTC() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.utc(2021, 07, 23, 00, 00, 00);
    int seconds = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
    print(seconds);
  }
```

I have created the date manually. You can pass the params as you want.